# vuejs2 child component data not updating in laravel5.4

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2

Here is my replies.vue file. Here what i am doing is when this **replies** component is created, i call a fetch() method that loads some data from the server:

```
//Replies.vue

<template>
  <div>   
    <div v-for="(reply, index) in replies_with_pagination.data">
        <reply :attributes="reply" :key="reply.id" :current_user_id="auth_user_id" @iamdeleted="updateCollection(index)"></reply>
    </div>

    <pagination :current_paginated_dataSet="replies_with_pagination"></pagination>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Reply from './Reply.vue';

export default{

    components: { Reply },

    props: ['all_replies','auth_user_id','thread_id'],

    data() {
        return {
            all_reply_items: this.all_replies,
            replies_with_pagination: '',
        }
    },

    methods: {
        fetch: function(){
              let vm = this;
              axios.get(route('replies.paginated',{ 'thread' : this.thread_id 
            }))
            .then(function(serverResponse){
                vm.replies_with_pagination = serverResponse.data;
            });
        },
    },

    created() {
        this.fetch();
    }
```

And then i am passing that to the **pagination** component via the **current_paginated_dataSet** props. Here is the code for pagination.vue

```
//Pagination.vue

<template>
   <div>
    <nav aria-label="...">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item disabled" v-show="current.prev_page_url">
          <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="page-item active">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li class="page-item" v-show="current.next_page_url">
          <a class="page-link" href="#">Next</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default{

    props: ['current_paginated_dataSet'],

    data() {
        return {
            current: this.current_paginated_dataSet,
        }
    },
 }
</script>
```

As you can see i am using this property to initialize a data called **current** in the pagination component. This **current_paginated_dataSet** property was initialized at the **replies** component to the value of FALSE, which, upon fetching the data from server was then reset to some object returned by the server.

My problem is the **previous** and **next** buttons on the pagination component are not visible. It seems the **current** data property on the pagination component is not getting the updated value from the replies component which updates after loading data from server. It is always set to the intial value of FALSE that it received from parent root component.

What am i doing wrong here?

**EDIT**

it works if instead of referring to the **current** data property i directly refer to the **current_paginated_dataSet** props in the previous and next buttons, like so:

```
// this works:
<li class="page-item disabled" v-show="current_paginated_dataSet.prev_page_url">
   <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1">Previous</a>
</li>
```

But i want to achieve this by referring to the data property **current**. How can i do that?